# Декомпозиция Университета, UML диаграмма-классов

Tags: ооп, uml

Правильно ли выполнена декомпозиция Университета (упрощенная форма без факультетов и курсов), особенно интересует Расписание? Если можно указать что именно не так!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание: Cделать декомпозицию университета: преподаватели, студенты, группы, аудитории, расписание занятий для студента и для преподавателя на день и на месяц в виде класс-диаграммы UML.

Comment: это сугубо индивидуальная работа. для нас может и правильная, но для твоего преподавателя, возможно, нет

Comment: Но может есть общие для всех замечания?

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем может кому-то пригодится как пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а есть ли пример реализации такой логики на языке программирования непосредственно?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Да остался еще